# Django form(set) - this field is required

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

When i am editing my form/formset and remove one ContestForm, in most of times it simply doesnt change and and i see error "this field is required"
e. g. there was "Form XYZ", i changed it to "----" (blank) and after submitting it shows "this field is required" as you can see in the screenshot
[image: This field is required]
Views.py:

```
def contest_admin(request, contest_slug):
    contest = get_object_or_404(Contest, slug=contest_slug)
    ontestFormsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Contest,
                                            ContestForms,
                                            fields=('form', 'main_entry', 'user_modifiable',),
                                            extra=2,
                                            )
    contest_desc = ContestDescForm(request.POST or None, instance=contest)
    contest_forms = ContestFormsFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=contest)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if contest_desc.is_valid() and contest_forms.is_valid():
            contest_desc.save()
            contest_forms.save()
    context = {
        ...
    }
    template_name = "contests/admin/_admin.html"
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Models.py:

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Contest Name', max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    capacity = models.IntegerField('Capacity')
    team_size = models.IntegerField('Team size', default=1)
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=1000)
    date_opened = models.DateField('Date opened')
    date_registration_closed = models.DateField('Date registration closed')
    date_closed = models.DateField('Date closed')
    forms = models.ManyToManyField(FormEntry, through='ContestForms')

class ContestForms(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    form = models.OneToOneField(FormEntry)
    main_entry = models.BooleanField('Main entry')
    user_modifiable = models.BooleanField('Modifiable')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "ContestForms"
```

Forms.py:

```
class ContestDescForm(forms.ModelForm):
    widget_attrs = {
    'class': "form-control",
    'type': 'date',
}
    description = CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    date_opened = DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    date_registration_closed = DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))
    date_closed = DateField(widget=DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Contest
        exclude = ('slug', 'forms',)


class ContestFormsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    form = ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=FormEntry.objects.all())

class Meta:
    model = ContestForms
    exclude = ()
```

**EDIT:**
Template:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ contest_desc|bootstrap }}
            <table>
            {{ contest_forms|bootstrap_inline }}
            </table>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You should add blank=True, in each field in models.py that you want to let the possiblity to be empty

Comment: I' dont think that it's a solution - when i leave Contest in ContestForm blank, i expect that ContestForm entry will be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to add blank=True ?

```
class Contest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Contest Name', max_length=100,blank=True)

class ContestForms(models.Model):
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
```